# Time Tracking: Does Turboshaft count towards Turbine time?

Tags: turbine, insurance, time

*another edit*
To clarify - I'm programming an application for logbook tracking and want to automate turbine time calculations to help people fill in insurance firms easily.

**edit**: I guess a more general way to ask this is do *you* consider turbo shaft to count towards turbine time? Do insurance companies have a standard opinion?

**original question**:
For insurance forms, when you are asked your turbine time, do you include all of the following in that hour calculation:

- Turboprop
- Turbojet
- Turboshaft

I want to make sure I'm not short changing my time, but don't want to put some helicopter specific turbine in my time if that isn't correct. As far as I'm concerned they *should* count, right? It is, after all, only asking about the source of thrust not category of aircraft...

Thanks!

Comment: Ask your insurance company what they will accept. Insurers' policies differ, and insurance companies can be very picky about declarations on a proposal form if they think they might be substantially out of pocket.

Comment: I don't want to be unhelpful, but what I or anyone else thinks about this is completely irrelevant. The only opinion that counts is the one from your insurance company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turbine is turbine.  If you burn fuel to spin a turbine that drives a compressor, it's turbine.

I counted all turboshaft time as "turbine" when reviewing resumes for pilot applicants.  Understanding the theory behind turbine engine operation is what everyone cares about, whether is was a turbo-this or a turbo-that is not as important.

Contact a few insurance brokers just to be sure.  Falcon Insurance, AOPA, TrueCourse just to name a few.

Comment: This confirms my thinking - and gives me some direction as to where to go for more information. Thanks.